# Add p-values/significance to ALL boxplots (pairwise) in facet_wrapped plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, significance

I have a facet_wrapped plot with 5 facets, that have different numbers of boxplots in them.

I wanna pairwise compare all of them if they differ siginficantly from each other, ideally already giving the p-value IN the graph.
[image: see here]

My code:

```
data.csv %>%
  group_by(method, year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(crop, H, fill = crop)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Shannon Index per field") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "antiquewhite4", "burlywood4", "cornsilk2",
      "cornsilk", "antiquewhite3", "antiquewhite2"
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~method, scales = "free_x") +
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = crop), label = "p.signif")
```

What I tried:

- `stat_compare_means` -> doesn't seem to work, gives the wrong values (I think it compares ALL barleys with ALL whetas and not only the ones IN one of the facets).
- `stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test)` -> gives me errors, doesn't find object stat.test no matter how I put the object before

What I need:
for it to work without making every facet a single boxplot graph and then adding all together later
thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data (e.g. a built-in dataset or from one of the default examples) shared using `dput()`.

Comment: I have never worked with the built in datasets or created fake ones.. it would work with any that can build boxplots and facet with a third category.

Comment: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-to-ggplot-facets/
this is basically similar to what I need, but doesn't work

Comment: Hej Laura. That would have been my suggestion, too (:. But of course do well still need your code to figure out what's different and what might be the issue.

Comment: data.csv %>% group_by(method, year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(crop, H, fill=crop))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x = "", y = "Shannon Index per field")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("antiquewhite4","burlywood4","cornsilk2","cornsilk", "antiquewhite3", "antiquewhite2"))+
  facet_wrap(~method, scales="free_x")+
  stat_compare_means(aes(group=crop), label="p.signif")